# Mysql Query to get category name along with Parent category name till root category

Tags: mysql

I have a category table with following fields:

| id | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Cat 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Cat 2 |
| 3 | 1 | Cat 3 |
| 4 | 2 | Cat 4 |

I need a SQL query through which I can get results like below:

| id | parent_id | name | full_path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Cat 1 | Cat 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 1 > Cat 2 |
| 3 | 1 | Cat 3 | Cat 1 > Cat 3 |
| 4 | 2 | Cat 4 | Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 4 |

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using version 5.7.26

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (1,0,'Cat 1'),(2,1,'Cat 2'),(3,1,'Cat 3'),(4,2,'Cat 4');

SELECT
   id,
   parent_id,
   name,
   CONCAT(COALESCE((SELECT CONCAT(c3.name,' > ') FROM category c3 WHERE c3.id=(SELECT c4.parent_id FROM category c4 WHERE c4.id=c1.parent_id)),''),
     COALESCE((SELECT CONCAT(c2.name,' > ') FROM category c2 WHERE c2.id=c1.parent_id),''),
     name) as full_path
FROM category c1;
```

output:

```
+------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
| id   | parent_id | name  | full_path             |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
|    1 |         0 | Cat 1 | Cat 1                 |
|    2 |         1 | Cat 2 | Cat 1 > Cat 2         |
|    3 |         1 | Cat 3 | Cat 1 > Cat 3         |
|    4 |         2 | Cat 4 | Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 4 |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
```

This 'solution' will stop at a depth of 3 levels.

For MYSQL8.0, a better readable solution can be created using [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte as (
   select 
      id, 
      parent_id, 
      name,
      CAST(name as char(100)) as full_path,
      parent_id p,
      1 as x
   from category
   union all
   select 
      cte.id, 
      cte.parent_id, 
      cte.name,
      CONCAT(category.name,' > ',cte.full_path) as full_path,
      category.parent_id,
      x+1
   from cte
   inner join category on category.id=cte.p
   where cte.p<>0 and x<=5
   ) 
select * from cte where p=0;
```

output:

````
+------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------+------+
| id   | parent_id | name  | full_path             | p    | x    |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------+------+
|    1 |         0 | Cat 1 | Cat 1                 |    0 |    1 |
|    3 |         1 | Cat 3 | Cat 1 > Cat 3         |    0 |    2 |
|    2 |         1 | Cat 2 | Cat 1 > Cat 2         |    0 |    2 |
|    4 |         2 | Cat 4 | Cat 1 > Cat 2 > Cat 4 |    0 |    3 |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------+------+```

Columns `p` and `x` where added because of debugging...
````